# step AIC (R) with weights

Tags: logistic, weighted-regression, stepwise-regression

Is there a way to introduce weights in step AIC (R) (stepwise with Akaike criterion).
For example, I would need to choose among many variables:

```
  FF<-as.formula(logPorcDeb~diaDesdePago)

  FFS<-as.formula(logPorcDeb~diaDesdePago+fl_1erdia+fl_2dodia+
                  flSab+flLun +flDpViernes+flGenteUltDias +....)
```

normally I would do:

```
library(MASS)
mod1 = glm(FF, data = trainR5)
mod1 = stepAIC(mod1, scope=list(upper=FFS, lower=FF), family=binomial, data = trainR5, k = 4)
```

I would get:

```
Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -3.775206   0.076098 -49.610  < 2e-16 ***
diaDesdePago   -0.144351   0.004603 -31.358  < 2e-16 ***
fl_1erdia       2.286391   0.114103  20.038  < 2e-16 ***
fl_2dodia       0.900298   0.143623   6.268 4.10e-10 ***
flGenteUltDias -0.402814   0.072993  -5.519 3.67e-08 ***
flDpViernes     1.296299   0.139703   9.279  < 2e-16 ***
flSab          -1.627571   0.202970  -8.019 1.45e-15 ***
flLun           0.387128   0.082355   4.701 2.69e-06 ***
```

But since I need to give more importance to instances according to another variable.

```
mod1 = glm(FFS, data = trainR5, weights=trainR5$ponderador)

And I get:
Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -2.714319   0.030913 -87.804  < 2e-16 ***
diaDesdePago   -0.152839   0.003614 -42.296  < 2e-16 ***
fl_1erdia       1.970443   0.030711  64.162  < 2e-16 ***
fl_2dodia       0.579073   0.036424  15.898  < 2e-16 ***
flSab          -1.080402   0.082579 -13.083  < 2e-16 ***
flLun           0.116103   0.021245   5.465 5.03e-08 ***
flDpViernes     0.161092   0.029382   5.483 4.55e-08 ***
flGenteUltDias  0.019830   0.016907   1.173    0.241
```

If I add the stepwise code and put FF formula in the first line, it doesn't work (doesn't include the coefficients in the FFS formula).

What I would like to do is to include weights also in the stepwise procedure. How can I do this without having to manually oversample the data to respect the desired weights?

Thanks.

Comment: "I need to give more importance to instances according to another variable." what does that mean? You can weight observations with the `weights` argument in `gym`. Do you want to prespecify importance weights to variables? Just do stepwise by hand, making use of `drop1` and `add1`. Look at the workhorse for `stepAIC`.

Comment: @AdamO, thanks, can you post an example code of doing manually stepAIC?